# CoreBluetooth in Background at Scheduled Time

Tags: ios, background, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

**Problem:** I need to remain disconnected from a BLE peripheral but send data it's data to a server for processing as often as possible, as it is potentially time-critical.  In other words, I want to connect every so often and send the synced data to an API, while remaining disconnected at all other times to save battery life.

**Failed Attempt:** Setting the `UIBackgroundModes` field of my app's Info.plist file to `bluetooth-central` only gives me background execution while I am connected. I want to remain disconnected, but reconnect at predefined intervals, as well as schedule an alarm from background mode.

**It's possible:** I've noticed that the FitBit Flex app has an option in the settings to enable syncing in the background.  I am not sure if it ever disconnects from my Flex while it is in range, but judging its so-small-I'd-lose-it battery size, I'm guessing it does not remain connected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know I've already accepted an answer for this (sorry!), but I've found a solution:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:60*5]; // Every 5 minutes, minimum
```

in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and adding `fetch` to `UIBackgroundModes`, which iOS then calls:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

every 15-240 minutes (yeah, it varies a *lot*, but it's better than nothing).  Every time I am called to perform a fetch, I connect to the peripheral, sync and send its data to the server, then disconnect.  Since I'm  sending this data from the BLE peripheral to a server for processing/storage, I'm presuming that this is a legitimate (AppStore worthy) use of `fetch`.

**CAVEAT:** `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` will *not* be called until iOS establishes a user usage pattern for the app.  In other words, you need to keep the app around (not delete it) for about 24 hours or so before the `application:performFetch...` method gets called.  Boy, did it take a while to figure that out!

**UPDATE:** Apple has accepted my app that used this solution (approved May 2014).

Comment: Very clever solution. Definitely a way to go for scenarios like yours.

Comment: BTW can you add a little more detail on how you test this? Do you simply connect when resumed?

Comment: Every time `performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` is called, I connect to the BLE peripheral, which then gives me unrestricted background execution using the `bluetooth-central` UIBackgroundMode (read: no execution expiration).  Essentially, I'm using the `fetch` privilege and trading it for the `bluetooth-central` privilege.  When I'm done doing my thing, I disconnect.

Comment: @cbh2000 This is the method I've incorporated into my app as well.  I have not yet submitted to the app store, and was looking in SO to determine if there will be any issues with approval from Apple, when I found this post.  Have you submitted your app with no issues?

Comment: I have not submitted the app yet, but will in the next month.  I'll let you know.

Comment: @steve We still haven't submitted yet.  I haven't forgotten. :-)

Comment: @steve Just letting you know that my app's been accepted and I'm using this technique.

Comment: @cbh2000 Congratulations on the successful launch of your app!  And thank you for keeping me updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A backgrounded app cannot start any transactions, it can only react to incoming requests (data notifications, connection events...) In the background the application is effectively not running and even in case of BLE events it has only 8 seconds to go back to sleep, otherwise it is completely terminated for breaking the policy.

The only case when your app can stay alive for a while is when it uses the `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` API. But even in that case it has only 10 minutes to complete or it gets killed.

If you want to synchronize while in background, then the transaction must be started on the external peripheral's side. Easiest is to stay connected and send a notification to the central every once in a while. That will wake it up and it can proceed with reading the characteristics it needs. But there are several other ways to implement it. The final solution has to be designed to best meet your needs. If you have a concrete idea, then please submit it as a separate question.

Comment: Forgive me if this is the wrong way to think about it, but what about asking for a connection at the end of the 10 minutes?  In this case the app will either gain background permission from a connection or CoreBluetooth will connect to it automatically when it comes back in range, which would give me background permission also.  After that, is it possible to chain the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: request with another scheduled timer at just under ten minutes?

Comment: You can try it. "You can call this method at any point in your app’s execution." && "You should not use this method simply to keep your app running after it moves to the background." (quote from the documentation) I'm pretty sure that you would not be admitted in the App Store. If this is not your goal, then go ahead and do whatever you need. :)

Comment: I guess if you are developing the peripheral, then it is safer to make that wake up after some time.

Comment: If you create a test project, then share it with us please and publish your experimental results. This is a greyish area of the documentation, so evidence would be very helful.

Comment: Sounds good, but as we are developing the hardware ourselves, that sounds like the area we do have control over.  Putting the device into sleep mode and scheduling a wake-up sounds like the only real solution we have here.  Obviously, that's not the solution I was hoping for, but it might work.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: As it turns out, it is possible to connect in the background while remaining disconnected.  See my answer for details.  Needless to say, I'm pretty excited!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

I'm pretty sure you guys have seen this, but just in case you haven't. Perhaps on the BLE Peripheral end you can save power by increasing the connection interval (page 22).

Comment: Thanks for the good point.  Unfortunately, we are having a hard time getting our hardware to communicate changes in the connection interval while maintaining a connection.  It might be a bug in our firmware, or maybe iOS is picky about connection interval changes, but whenever we change the rate it disconnects and the changes are not applied/honored.