# How to run a Bluetooth Le scan in background with locked screen

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

On iOS, in background mode (So with screen off for instance) I would like to make a bluetooth scan every 30 minutes to get advertisement data coming from a Bluetooth LE device.

In visual studio, in info.plist file i have activated "Enable background Modes" to be able to run background process and then "Uses Bluetooth LE accessory" but i don't know what to do with that ... .

I have also tried to use "background fetch" but this is raised only whenever iOS wants .... so it doesn't fit to my need.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);
    return true;
}
public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    //do job
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
}
```

Step reproduce

1.Open my app

2.Lock the screen

3.After 30 minutes, the app(in a service) do a scan and get data from Bluetooth LE broadcast data

Expected result: 
Get advertisement data from my BluetoothLe device (SO without connection)

Comment: When scanning in the background you must scan for a specific service that your peripheral is advertising and you will only get a discovery callback for a peripheral that your app hasn't already discovered during the current run. Once you have enabled Bluetooth background mode, as long as you have a specific service scan in effect you will get a background launch when a new peripheral is discovered.  You cannot discover all currently advertising peripherals every 30 minutes

Comment: Can I wake up the Iphone every 30 minutes to try to make a connection to the bluetoothLe Device ?

Comment: No.  You can't schedule actions for specific intervals in the background on iOS.  Typically you would have the iOS device maintain a connection to the device and have the device push new information periodically

Comment: So if i do not maintain an active connection, I have no chance to get data from bluetooth device automatically if the Iphone goes to sleep ?

Comment: And what about use PerformFetch and then use bluetooth-central to get rid of the expiration background time ? 

I found that comment on StackOverFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694978/corebluetooth-in-background-at-scheduled-time#comment32182222_21299954

Comment: You can use background fetch to periodically connect to your peripheral but you can't schedule the interval and it won't be every 30 minutes. It might be a few times per day

Comment: Is it possible to have scan interval with no constraint time but more than only few per days ?

Comment: You can minimum time, but iOS will tune your dispatch frequency by observing what you do when the background fetch is invoked; do you actually perform a network operation, how long do you run for, how much battery did you use etc